# Text Cutting inside Large Select Option Dropdown

Tags: html, css, select, html-select

I am making a UI full of form elements and I want all elements to be big sizes elements. But dropdown really issues as the text in cutting. No line height, no padding is able to fix the issue. I am using Bootstrap v3 as UI framework on my application. I am using Open Sans font.

**Here is what it's looking like:**

[image: Dropdown issues]

**Here is the code, I am using:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Reference</label>
<select class="form-control text-center"  readonly="">
<option>Choose...</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 5vh;
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

I have tried some solutions but they are not working for me.

**Decreasing font:**

[image: Decreasing font]

**Increasing Height of dropdown or making height auto:**

[image: Increasing Height of dropdown or making height auto]

I looking for the solution this issue, but no help I found in Stack Overflow. Could it be resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You can **increase the height** of your select box, like so:

```css
select.form-control  { //only targets select boxes with a class of form-control
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 15vh; //or min-height: 15vh; 
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control text-center"  readonly="">
<option>Choose...</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

2. **Without** setting a height :

```css
select.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control text-center"  readonly="">
<option>Choose...</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Helenesh, thanks for the reply. Actually, the issue is regarding select dropdown only. The all types of input fields, checkboxes and radios are looking fine. Increasing the height of the select dropdown would make the layout disaligned. i need something specific for select dropdown.

Comment: @SaurabhLP Then you can simply target the select boxes only. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Helenesh, 15vh will be too large. I cant apply it. I want everything inside 5vh only. Any solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look at the differences.

Comment: @SaurabhLP What if you set the line-height to 5vh? I think you already tried that? Also, your new screenshots are not clear. You do not say what the problem is.

Comment: Helenesh, Line height is not working at all. Line height is non-functional at all in my case. Issue is simply, i dont want to increase the height or font size, but the text should not cut too.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label>Reference</label>
<select class="form-control text-center"  readonly="">
<option>Choose...</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

You can fix this by either increasing the height of form-control or removing the height attribute from the form control so that the select field height wraps around the text.

Comment: Please expand this with some example code to show what you mean

Comment: Hi sneha, thanks for the reply. After removing height attribute, the dropdown became much large and had extra spacing inside the dropdown and height I cant increase because all types of inputs, checkboxes, and radios are looking fine.

Comment: Hi @SaurabhLP , do you want the font size to be 5vh only or will it be variable ?

Comment: Hi Sneha, yes I want font size also 5vh too.

Comment: Done @AonghasM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

removed `height: 15vh;` and it is working as expected. hope this helps. thanks

```css
label {
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label>Reference</label>
<select class="form-control text-center"  readonly="">
<option>Choose...</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height:5vh` instead of height on select box. It may fix the issue.

```
.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 5vh;
    font-size: 5vh;
    border-radius: 1.8vh;
    border-width: 0.1vh;
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, unfortunately, it should work and that should fix my issue. But sorry to say, it's not working at all. Line height is non-functional at all in my case...

Comment: please can you share the screenshot with other input element what exactly you want..

Comment: I had. Please look at the question.

Comment: please take a screenshot with other elements (example with text box and any other element) just want to compare the design between other elements.. thats why